# Change Python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long string that looks like below. This is a small part of it, but the pattern repeat.

The raw data that I get when I read the API with Requests:

```
...
}
#VER B 160 20201020 "Test Bolag AB (4117)" 20201223
{
#TRANS 3001 {6 "1000050"} -180000 "" "" 0
#TRANS 2611 {6 "1000050"} -45000 "" "" 0
#TRANS 1510 {6 "1000050"} 225000 "" "" 0
}
#VER A 2 20200212 "Test Bolag AB1" 20201223
{
#TRANS 1930 {} -7549 "" "" 0
#TRANS 2641 {} 1209.75 "" "" 0
#TRANS 7990 {} 6339.25 "" "" 0
}
...
```

The code I've written now:

```
lst = r.text.split('}\r\n')

for i in range(len(lst)):
    tmpstr1 = str(lst[i])
    tmpstr2 = tmpstr1.replace(" ",";")
    tmpstr3 = tmpstr2.replace("\\r","")
    tmpstr4 = tmpstr3.replace("\\n","")
    tmpstr5 = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9;,#-.]', '', tmpstr4)
    tmpstr6 = tmpstr5.replace("#VER;","")
    tmplst1 = tmpstr6.split('#TRANS;')
    tmpstr7 = str(tmplst1)
    tmpstr8 = str(tmplst1[0])
    tmpstr9 = tmpstr7.replace(";0",tmpstr8)
    tmpstr10 = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9;,-]', '', tmpstr9)
    tmpstr11 = tmpstr10.strip()

    tmplst2 = tmpstr11.split(',')
    tmplst2.pop(0)
    lst[i] = str(tmplst2)

print(lst[200])
```

This is what I get now:

```
['3001;6;1000050;-180000;;B;160;20201020;Kundfaktura;Test;Bolag;AB;4117;20201223', '2611;6;1000050;-45000;;B;160;20201020;Kundfaktura;Test;Bolag;AB;4117;20201223', '1510;6;1000050;225000;;B;160;20201020;Kundfaktura;Test;Bolag;AB;4117;20201223']
```

This is what I want to get:

```
3001;6;1000050;-180000;;B;160;20201020;Kundfaktura;Test Bolag AB;4117;20201223 
2611;6;1000050;-45000;;B;160;20201020;Kundfaktura;Test Bolag AB;4117;20201223 
1510;6;1000050;225000;;B;160;20201020;Kundfaktura;Test Bolag AB;4117;20201223
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't mentioned the problem you are facing. How someone in the community could help you.

Comment: Youre printing a list of strings. If you want to join them to create one string, use `print('\n'.join(lst))`

Comment: @ iamimran, The solution I come up with doesnt get me the result that I want. So what I am asking for is more a guidance in the right direction what do look for to get the result that I want.

Answer (score -1):

Just save them in arrays of an array.
So you would get every entry in an array, which will make it more dynamically for future use.
For this define an array and append after every for loop.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you post your text, so I can try your code and optimize it.

Comment: The r.text is 14000 rows, but in the first "Codebox" in my post is a small part of it, and it just goes on with the same structure but different numbers.